# is it possible to get the real status of accessiable of url when using rust

Tags: http, rust

when I using this code to get the response status of url:

```
use reqwest::{Client, header::{HeaderValue, HeaderMap}};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let client = Client::builder().danger_accept_invalid_certs(true).build().unwrap_or_default();
    let response = client.get("http://mang0.me/atom.xml").headers(construct_headers()).send().await; 
    match response {
        Ok(resp)=>{
            let txt = resp.text().await;
            println!("success response:{}", txt.unwrap_or_default());
        },
        Err(err) => {
            println!("code:{},error:{}",err.status().unwrap_or_default(),err);
        },
    }
}

fn construct_headers() -> HeaderMap {
    let mut headers = HeaderMap::new();
    headers.insert("User-Agent", HeaderValue::from_static("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"));
    headers.insert("Accept", HeaderValue::from_static("text/html"));
    headers.insert(
        "Referer",
        HeaderValue::from_static("https://www.google.com"),
    );
    headers
}
```

the log output is :

```
code:200 OK,error:error sending request for url (http://mang0.me/atom.xml): connection closed before message completed
```

why the status still be ok even through the url could not complete with service. what should I do to get the real status of the url accessabile.

Comment: "connection closed before message completed" -> there's an error during the request, so you can't get an HTTP status code because it's the request in itself that has an error. You get an HTTP status code when the request succeeds, and it does even if the status code is an error code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status code returned by `status` is a HTTP status code, so providing a value depends on a complet HTTP response, but the error message you receive tells us that there was no complete HTTP message received, so there isn't a HTTP status code.

You get 200 here because your call to  `status()` produces `None` and you then `unwrap_or_default()` it to the [`Default` of `StatusCode::Ok`](https://docs.rs/http/0.2.9/src/http/status.rs.html#229)

To see the real status code of the request you can just print it with debug formatting without defaulting it:

```rust
eprintln!("code:{:?}, error:{}", err.status(), err);
```